# References issue in Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro code to automate a process. Its running fine on my machine but when user is running it on his machine then it is showing error. Complile Error Can't find Project or Library. When I checked on the user's machine under references it was showing
missing Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library
and
missing Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library. How to get out of this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Librairies are unchecked or missing in the references?

Comment: It helps if you post relevant code snippets. Also, if you resolved your issue, post it as an answer and accept it, even if you answered it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer but a request for clarification.

If you open the workbook, open VB editor, select tools and then references you will get an list of hundreds of available libraries.  The top few libraries will be ticked but most will be unticked.

Are you saying that:

1) you do not get a list of hundreds of available libraries?
2) you have scrolled down the list and have failed to find the entries for Microsoft  Outlook 11.0 Object Library and Microsoft Word 11.0 Object Library?
3) you have found these entries but have not clicked on the little box to select them?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue is resolved now. I unchecked the missing entries and then tried to run the macro. It showed error for some keywords but somehow managed to find the replacement for those.